# BasicSearch in FilterBar does not work

Tags: sapui5

I declare a Search Field and add it to a Filter Bar. The code does not work but also does not return anything in the console.

Can anyone show me what is wrong with this and why it is not working?

Regards,

Binh

This is the Search Field

```js
if (oFilterBar.setBasicSearch) {
  oFilterBar.setBasicSearch(new sap.m.SearchField({
    showSearchButton: sap.ui.Device.system.phone,
    placeholder: "Search",
    liveChange: function() {
      oValueHelpDialog.getFilterBar().search();  
  }));
}

oValueHelpDialog.setFilterBar(oFilterBar);
```

then add it to this Filter Bar

```js
var oFilterBar = new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar({
  ...
  filterGroupItems: [
    new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterGroupItem({
      groupTitle: "foo",
      groupName: "gn1",
      name: "n1",
      label: "Supplier ID",
      control: new sap.m.Input()
    }),
    new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterGroupItem({
      groupTitle: "foo",
      groupName: "gn1",
      name: "n2",
      label: "Company Name",
      control: new sap.m.Input()
    })
  ],
  search: function(oEvent) {
    var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
    var oBarContent = oSource.getContent();
    var oToolBarContent = oBarContent[0].getContent();
    var oSearch = oToolBarContent[1];
    var sQuery = oSearch.getValue();

    return [
      new sap.ui.model.Filter(
        "Supplier ID",
        sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
        sQuery
      ),
      new sap.ui.model.Filter(
        "Company Name",
        sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains,
        sQuery
      )
    ];
  }
});
```

Comment: You dont have to return the Filters, You have to insert the filters where need filter (like a table,list, etc)

Comment: hi @I.B.N. the filter is in the `search` function inside a `valueHelpDialog`. How can I insert the filter into the target, I'm using a `columnListItem`? I did some search and it's only result to do with a proper `table`. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I don't have to call `oValueHelpDialog.getFilterBar().search();`. It can be deleted without any issue.

Instead, I put everything inside the `if` clause

```js
if (oFilterBar.setBasicSearch) {
  oFilterBar.setBasicSearch(new sap.m.SearchField({
    showSearchButton: sap.ui.Device.system.phone,
    placeholder: "Search",
    search: function(oEvent) {
      var oBinding = oValueHelpDialog.getTable().getBinding("items");
      var sQuery = oEvent.getParameter("query");
      var aFilter1 = [
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("SupplierID", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, sQuery),
        new sap.ui.model.Filter("CompanyName", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery)
      ];
      var allFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter(aFilter1 , false);
      oBinding.filter(allFilter);
    }
  }));
}

oValueHelpDialog.setFilterBar(oFilterBar);
```